# a:active background image?

Tags: css, image, background, hover

At [my website](http://mmd3e12dae42.keaweb.dk) I would like to make the dots in the side change when I'm on the active div box. The hover works fine, but I can't get the active to work. The path for the image is worked fine, when I tried to put it under hover.

```
#nav{
    z-index: 5;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
}

#nav li {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: transparent url('images/dot.png') no-repeat;    
    opacity: 0.80;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    opacity: 1; 
}

#nav li a:active {
    background: transparent url('images/dotactive.png') no-repeat;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible for the image to stay as the active background with just CSS alone. You will need to use a combination of javascript too.

With jQuery you could try something like the below.

```
.active{background: url('images/dotactive.png') no-repeat !important;}

$('#nav li a').live('click',function () {
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});​
```

**EDIT** A Workign fiddle of your site keeping the active nav background images. http://jsfiddle.net/ukCG8/

Comment: Thx a lot! This was very helpfull.
But sadly it gives me another problem. If people scroll down the page, then the "active" will be at a wrong place. Is it possible to maybe disallow scrolling?

Comment: @McKeene Yes this is possible too, if you add `body{overflow:hidden}` This will remove the scroll bars and will prevent users from scrolling. Glad I could help.
**EDIT* I've updated the fiddle to demonstrate this. http://jsfiddle.net/ukCG8/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
    background: url('images/dotactive.png') no-repeat;
```

no need for transparent

or use opacity also for tranparency

Comment: The active image seems to appear fine with 'transparent' in anyway, I assume McKeene wan't the image to stay active while on that page.

Comment: @vletech he can use opacity to cover the transparency

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
var Lst;

function CngClass(obj){
 if (Lst) Lst.className='';
 obj.className='selected';
 Lst=obj;
}

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

And modify the li items like this:

```
<li>
<a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Test 1
</a>
</li>
```

I wish I could take credit for the fix; check it out in action [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?167660-onclick-change-class-remove-when-next-link-clicked) (yes, I'm cheating on stackOverflow with another web dev site!)